# the sum of the all integers from a to b, What's Wrong With My Code?

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket, r5rs

The goal is to create a code that will compute the sum of all integers from a to b
and if a > b then it should evaluate to 0.

```
(define (sum-from-to a b)
  (if (> a b)
      0
      (+ a (sum-from-to (- a 1) b))))
```

My problem is that when I run this, I run out of memory. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Hint: Suppose your list of integers is `{1, 2, 3}` whereby `a = 1` and `b = 3`. Think about what is produced by `(- a 1)`.

Comment: Is the code required to be recursive?

Answer (score 2):

The recursive step is incorrect. Assuming that `a <= b` the fix is as simple as this:

```
(define (sum-from-to a b)
  (if (> a b)
      0
      (+ a (sum-from-to (+ a 1) b)))) ; add 1, don't subtract
```

Think about it, we want `a` to become closer to `b` at each step, until it jumps over it. If we *decrease* `a`, then it'll move away from `b`, the exact opposite of what we want. That's why your procedure runs out of memory, `a` never reached `b`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, here's one answer a mathematician would give: the sum of all integers from `a` to `b` is half of the sum of integers from `a` to `b` plus the sum of all integers from `b` to `a`.  And this is `a + b + a + 1 + b - 1 + ... + b + a` which is `a + b + a + b + ... + a + b`.  And this in turn is `(a + b) * (b - a + 1)`.  So the final sum is `(a + b) * (a - b + 1) / 2` therefore.  So just write that in Lisp, with the additional condition specified that for `b < a`:

```
(define (sum-a-b a b)
  (if (> a b)
      0
      (/ (* (+ a b) (+ (- b a) 1)) 2)))
```

Of course, what is probably being looked for is either a recursive or an iterative answer.  Either of those is a terrible solution to the problem: the recursive answer is terrible in both time & space complexity while the iterative one is merely terrible in terms of time complexity.

People who teach Lisp should stop actively trying to teach people to program badly.

Comment: > *People who teach Lisp should stop actively trying to teach people to program badly.* I don't see an applause button, so upvote will have to do.

Comment: @Kaz Thanks.  It would be interesting to count the number of obvious-students asking for solutions to problems where there's a well-known closed-form.  It's reasonable, I suppose, that students don't know enough maths to know it, but their teachers should.  It's not like there aren't plenty of algorithms where there *isn't* a closed form.

Comment: There seems to be a problem of Lisp teachers not just teaching people how to program badly, but specifically teaching lousy Lisp that leaves a bad impression of the language family on students.

Comment: @Kaz: I think the argument is this is how we keep the language a secret known only by gurus.  Or they just can't program.